# Capture lines between specific keywords and print output

Tags: python, python-3.x

My input is a text file example which contains multiple lines like below

*input = " START*

*BEGIN*

*PROGRAM STARTED*

*PROGRAM IN PROGRESS*

*PAUSE*

*STOP"*

I want to capture lines between BEGIN AND PAUSE and print them as output.

I have written a code using regex but it is able to capture data only if search keywords are in the same line.

I need helpto fix this issue. search and capture data even if search keywords are in multiple lines.

Logic used

`output = re.findall('(?<=BEGIN)(.*?)(?=PAUSE)',re.MULTILINE, input)`

Comment: What should be the output if BEGIN exists but PAUSE doesn't?

Comment: [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) doesn't really makes a difference here (as you don't have `^` or `$`), what you need is [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)...

Comment: By the way your order of arguments is wrong. It should be `re.findall(pattern, string, flags)`

Comment: @Abhinav - input will have begin and pause for sure. So we can exclude that scenario.

Comment: @tomerikoo - i did some google search and found people suggesting re.Multiline. can you help me with code using re.dotall

Comment: @tomerikoo - can use share as an example regarding order of arguments.

Comment: Literally change the `re.MULTILINE` in your code to `re.DOTALL`. Read the links I provided to better understand them.  [This is](https://regex101.com/r/C6hSJu/1) with `MULTILINE` while [this is](https://regex101.com/r/SCqDnb/1) with `DOTALL`. And again, the order is exactly as I said above: `re.findall(pattern, string, flags)`

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach without regex is using `.split`:

```py
#input string
input_ = ''' START

BEGIN

PROGRAM STARTED

PROGRAM IN PROGRESS

PAUSE

STOP'''

#splits on "BEGIN" and gets last part stripped of newlines, so all after "BEGIN"
from_begin = input_.split("BEGIN")[-1].strip("/n")

#splits on "PAUSE" and gets first part stripped of newlines, so all before "PAUSE"
result = from_begin.split("PAUSE")[0].strip("/n")

#print result
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks dion. I'll try and share my inputs.

Comment: Apologies for the delay dion. i have tried the steps and it is working fine.
I have new problem, im' unable to capture all instance using the above script. I might have missed the point sorry for that. above program is capturing only first occurence. Can you help me capture all occurences.